Using jquery-editable-select in a Django App
This is my very first Django app so please don't be too harsh :-)
I'm trying to use jquery-editable-select in my Django web App but I'm lost.
https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select
According to this link, it seems like I need to install NPM first or Bower.
I don't know what these are, can someone give me the basics from scratch ?
Is it something to install via PIP like a python package ?

Just following the instructions on GitHub, this is as easy as loading the libraries. One option is to use those available on Github:
//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js

The other methods (npm/bower/git) allow you to download the libraries to your local machine.
Include this in your Javascript/JQuery code.


$('#editable-select').editableSelect();
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<select id="editable-select">
  <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
  <option>BMW</option>
  <option>Citroen</option>
</select>



